# NPM issue, where to start

Tags: node.js, npm

Hopefully this is the right forum to post. Coming stack overflow but I think this is more you guys' expertise.

I have a centos 6.10 box. It had Node.js and npm running ok. I don't know which versions of them were they. I tried to update them to the LTS by running

`sudo npm install n -g`

Now, whenever I run `npm` I get this error:

```
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
```

I tried to uninstall node and npm completely and reinstalling them, no luck there neither. Now I'm out of tricks. Can anybody help me with what should I do now please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CentOS is just too old.

You can check which package the library belongs to by running `yum provides /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`. In my case (on CentOS 7, but that doesn't matter for this) this is `libstdc++-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64`.

If you look up [the package for `libstdc++` for CentOS 6 on pkgs.com](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-x86_64/libstdc++-4.4.7-23.el6.x86_64.rpm.html) you'll see against which glibc headers it was compiled. In this case you see that the latest version was:

- libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.13)(64bit)

Your output shows that the newer npm version needs at least `GLIBCXX_3.4.14`.

I guess you can compile node.js yourself against the library versions you have available, but I'd rather update CentOS to a newer release. It will be [end of life anyway in November 2020](https://endoflife.software/operating-systems/linux/centos).

Comment: yea, it is an old centos, there are 2 old sites running on it that it. we have a few new boxes but my boss has no intention to retire the old ones. Anyways, i fixed the issue by running `n --arch x86 latest` and `yum install libstdc++-devel.i686`. Thanks for the help!